# Not able to edit page in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint

Not able to edit the home page of sharepoint2013 but we are able to edit all the site pages,
when trying to edit the home page it shows loading and not able to edit the page.Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use Sharepoint designer (download from : http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35491) then pointing at the home page file (could be at **/sitepages/home.aspx** if activate publishing site, or **/pages/default.aspx** if using default team site) then click **Advanced Mode** at ribbon.

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,is there any other fix other than doing it through sharepoint designer.

Comment: I think that is the best way since you say that directly editing to the page (using common **edit page**) in the sharepoint site is not working. cmiiw.

Answer (score 0):

The page is checked out by another user - just check it in and discard the other users changes (or find that other user and get them to check it in). You'll then see the full edit mode.